# mysql_field_name to the new mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a way to get the name of the columns of a table. It works fine but now I want to update to the new mysqli ? (I tried the mysqli_fetch_field but I don't know how to apply to this case and I am not sure if it is the wright option)

How to do the same with mysqli ? :

```
$sql = "SELECT * from myTable";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$id = mysql_field_name($result, 0);
$a = mysql_field_name($result, 1);

echo $id;
echo $a;
```

Comment: If you are going to use mysqli, all functions need to be converted to it. You can't mix mysql and mysqli.

Comment: mysql_field_name is already ancient and unusable way. Why do you need them, by the way?

Comment: That is the question: how to convert all to the new mysqli

Comment: What is your goal? What for do you need field names?

Comment: If you use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, to fetch the data, you will get the field names in the array, so you wouldn't need to query them separately. Also, it's generally considered good practice to list the fields you want in the query; ie use `SELECT fieldname, fieldname, etc` rather than `SELECT *`. If you do that, you'll already know what fields are in the results, so you wouldn't need to check back for the field list at all.

Comment: You can replace the `function mysql_field_name` to `mysqli_fetch_field_direct`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do that, but I checked that this works to get just the name of the columns and is the new mysqli :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM myTable');
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    echo $property->name;
}
```

Comment: if you need both the data and the metadata, you will lose the data. Also, this loop will go over the entire table. Also, given you are fetching anyway, why not just fetch the assoc array and use its keys?

Answer (score 44):

This is the way to implement this missing function:

```
function mysqli_field_name($result, $field_offset)
{
    $properties = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $field_offset);
    return is_object($properties) ? $properties->name : null;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer according the deprecation notice in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php), but the original function returned False on failure, not null.  Shouldn't you just forgo the ternary operator and do 
return $properties->name;  ?

Comment: Just change null to false.

Answer (score 7):

You can replace the function `mysql_field_name` to `mysqli_fetch_field_direct`and use it like the following:

```
$colObj = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i);                            
$col = $colObj->name;
echo "<br/>Coluna: ".$col;
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It is almost identical to mysql_field_name, except you have to de-reference the name:  $id = mysql_field_name($result, 0) =>  $id = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, 0)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 10";
$ressult = $con->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$fields = array_keys($rows[0] ?? []);
echo json_encode($fields);
```

Can return empty array if query returned no rows.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in php and I don't understand your answer. How can I pick up just the title of the field, like in the example I give.

Answer (score 1):

This is another easy way to print each field's name, table, and max length

```
$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   // Get field information for all fields
   while ($fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field($result))
   {
      printf("Name: %s\n",$fieldinfo->name);
      printf("Table: %s\n",$fieldinfo->table);
      printf("max. Len: %d\n",$fieldinfo->max_length);
   }
   // Free result set
   mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```