# Generating Documents such as EXCEL TXT, PDF from MYSQL DB data & which function replace mysq_field_name

Tags: php, excel, mysqli, pdf-generation

Guys lend me a hand by correcting my code bellow I would like to fetch some MYSQL DB fields to produce EXCEL and PDF file. On the heading part I need to add other two columns COMMENT and EXAM as well as be able to fill COMMENT and CLASS when the file is been generated using condition statement.

**NOTES:**

1. The code provided is able to generate EXCEL file using mysql not mysqli.
2. The score ($score) should have % e.g 20%
3. $comment condition example

> ```
> if($score < 35){
>     $comment = fail;
> }else{
>     $comment = pass;
> }
> ```

**Code Problems**

1. Can’t use mysqli_field_name but mysql_field_name (can you give explanation)

**CODE**

```
$sql            = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT firstname, lastname, student_id, score, sex
FROM students AS student
INNER JOIN scores AS score ON student.student_id = score.candidateid
WHERE score.subjectid = '200'

");
$columns_total  = mysqli_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading    =   strtoupper(mysqli_field_name($sql, $i));
    $output     .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}

// Download the file

$filename =  uniqid(time()).".csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
exit;
```

> Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you even tried searching for mysqli_field_name() and see if it is a valid function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629636/mysql-field-name-to-the-new-mysqli

Comment: search results shown its a function thats y i land here

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629636/mysql-field-name-to-the-new-mysqli?lq=1 check that out let us know if you need further help.

Comment: thanks Kypro for the reference mysqli_fetch_field_direct(); solve the heading problem. but how can i add columins which are not from sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make this a proper answer for future reference and to answer both your questions in the comments.

The answer to accessing the similar function for `mysqli` for mysql_field_name() you read [mysql_field_name to the new mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629636/mysql-field-name-to-the-new-mysqli?lq=1)

To add another column let's say if you passed as per your example since the result is build in lines, you append a check after the `for` loop :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading    =   strtoupper(mysqli_field_name($sql, $i));
    $output     .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output     .= '"PASSED?",';
$output .="\n";
```

and similarly inside the `while()` loop and after the `for()` loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
    }

    // add a pass column
    if($score < 35){
        $comment = "fail";
    }else{
        $comment = "pass";
    }

    $output     .= '"'.$comment.'"';

    $output .="\n";
 }
```

Haven't tested the code but this should be a working implementation to your question and comments

Comment: Consider it done your code give me basic understand so, i implementation my code to a working one. thanks